# how to plot each profile with a distance from the other in a 2D plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to plot something like this http://www.nature.com/nprot/journal/v9/n6/fig_tab/nprot.2014.090_F7.html or like this one http://file.scirp.org/Html/11-2200285/ff6819f9-5db9-4121-852d-a8d5c302a5a4.jpg I have a 2D matrix.

I tried to plot it like this but did not work

```
figure;
hold on
for i = 1:size(X,1)
 plot(X(i,:)+10)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not specify what exactly does not work, I am having some difficulties to answer your question directly (I do not have enough reputation for a comment).

The following code results in an image like the ones you link. Maybe you forgot to multiply the y-shift with the iteration number i.

```
N = 200;
x = 1:N;
M = 5;
X = sin(kron(x,ones(M,1)));

figure; hold all;
for i=1:N
    plot(X(i,:)+i*5);
end
```

Comment: do you know how to add the number of columns in front of each line ? for example in your example there are 5 lines, do you know how to do it?